# GraphQL api consuming with spring boot Resttemplate resulting in {"errors":[{"message":"No query string was present"}]} always

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, graphql-java

Currently we want to consume a graphQL endpoint in a springboot application using resttemplate

However, when we make a POST request with the below query we are always receiving the same error {"errors":[{"message":"No query string was present"}]}

Below is the snippet, we want to run,

```
    @Test
    public void testSwoop(){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer *************");
        headers.add("content-type", "application/graphql");

        String query1 = "{\n" +
                "  \"query\": query {\n" +
                "    \"locationTypes\": {\n" +
                "      \"edges\": \n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"node\": \n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"name\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        String URL = "https://staging.joinswoop.com/graphql";

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, new HttpEntity<>(query1, headers), String.class);
      System.out.println("The response================="+response);
    }
```

However from Postman, we dont have any issue in consuming the endpoint, and we get response just fine
[image: postman output]

Can someone please help us in directing us to the correct resource

Comment: Better to use GraphQLTestTemplate from graphql-spring-boot-starter-test. Then you can send the request using ```graphQLTestTemplate.postForResource("graphql/transaction.graphql")```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you set the content type header to "application/graphql", but yo are sending a JSON as data.
Two solutions that might work:

**Sending JSON:**

Set the content type to "application/json" and send a JSON formatted query:

```
@Test
public void testSwoop(){

    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer *************");
    headers.add("content-type", "application/json"); // just modified graphql into json

    String query1 = "{\n" +
            "  \"query\": query {\n" +
            "    \"locationTypes\": {\n" +
            "      \"edges\": \n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "          \"node\": \n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "          \"name\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";

    String URL = "https://staging.joinswoop.com/graphql";

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, new HttpEntity<>(query1, headers), String.class);
  System.out.println("The response================="+response);
}
```

**Sending GraphQL Query:**

If your server support this (it should), set the content type to "application/graphql", and send a real graphql query as a string.

```
@Test
public void testSwoop(){

    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer *************");
    headers.add("content-type", "application/graphql"); // maintain graphql

    // query is a grapql query wrapped into a String
    String query1 = "{\n" +
            "    locationTypes: {\n" +
            "      edges: \n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "          node: \n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "          name\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  }";

    String URL = "https://staging.joinswoop.com/graphql";

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(URL, new HttpEntity<>(query1, headers), String.class);
  System.out.println("The response================="+response);
}
```

Comment: how can we achieve this using the asychronous behavior.

Comment: Is it possible to add variables as well?

Comment: Only  ```headers.add("content-type", "application/json");``` worked for me. Seems GraphQL work with both GraphQl and Json data but the content-type must be Json